# No provider for ModalComponent

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am a beginner in angular so this question my be stupid. In our application all  forms are displayed in popup. In header section there are several tabs and i need to load the component on clicking the tab. Please look into the below code and suggest whats wrong with the code.

**Modal View**

```
<modal (dismissPopup)="dismiss($event)" #myModal [keyboard]="false" [cssClass]="'my-modal'" [backdrop]="'static'">
<modal-header [show-close]="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="top:-7px;left:0px;padding-left:0px;">
            <!-- Nav tabs --><div class="card">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active tab-content"><a class="popup-tab completed" id="lnkCounterParty" href="#"><span class="fa fa-university"></span> Counterparty <span class="fa fa-check-circle-o" style="font-size:13px;vertical-align:super;"></span></a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="tab-content"><a class="popup-tab" id="lnkParticipant" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Participant</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</modal-header>
<div class="clear"></div>
<cpdb-counterparty (dismissPopup)="dismiss($event)"></cpdb-counterparty>
```

**Modal Component**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'cpdb-modal-popup',
    templateUrl: 'app/modalPopup/modalPopup.component.html'
})


export class modalPopupComponent {
@ViewChild('myModal')

modal: ModalComponent;

constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
}

openCounterpartyAddress() {
    debugger;
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(addressComponent);
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

open() {
    this.modal.open();
}

close() {
    this.modal.close();
 }

}
```

Above code snippet is for modal popup

**Tab 1 View**

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(AddressForm.valid)">
<modal-body>
    <div class="container-fluid fundmodal">
        <!-- Search Panel -->

    </div>

</modal-body>
<modal-footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="resetForm()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!counterPartyForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</modal-footer>
```

**Tab 1 Component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
selector: 'cpdb-address',
templateUrl: 'app/address/address.component.html',
outputs: ['dismissPopup']


})

export class addressComponent {
addressForm = new FormGroup({

});

//constructor(private helloWorldService: HelloWorldService) {
//}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

}

//private getAnswer() {
//    return this.helloWorldService.giveMeTheAnswer();
//}

onSubmit(isFormValid: boolean) {
}

resetForm() {
    this.addressForm = new FormGroup({

    });

}
```

}

**Tab View 2**

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" novalidate 
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(AddressForm.valid)">
<modal-body>
    <div class="container-fluid fundmodal">
        <!-- Search Panel -->

    </div>

</modal-body>
<modal-footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="resetForm()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!counterPartyForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</modal-footer>
```

**Tab 2 Component**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'cpdb-counterparty',
  templateUrl: 'app/counterparty/abc.component.html',
  outputs: ['dismissPopup']
})

export class counterPartyComponent {

dismissPopup = new EventEmitter<string>();

public submitted: boolean;
public IsSeiClient: boolean = false;



onSubmit(isFormValid: boolean) {
    if (isFormValid) {
        console.log(this.counterPartyForm.value);
    }
    else {
        this.submitted = true;
    }
}



resetForm() {
    this.counterPartyForm = new FormGroup({

    });

}
```

}

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, Ng2Bs3ModalModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
declarations: [AppComponent, tab1Component, tab2Component],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
entryComponents: [addressComponent],
providers: [
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
]
```

})

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of the tabs, that there is only one tab active, you can easily have a trigger to open the tabs. like:

in component you have :

```
public activeTab = '';
```

and on each tab, you edit the string:

```
<li (click)="activeTab = 'Counterparty'">
    <p>Counterparty</p>
</li>
<li (click)="activeTab = 'Participant'">
    <p>Participant</p>
</li> ......
```

and on the div where you want to active the tab:

```
<counter-party *ngIf="activeTab === 'Counterparty'"></counter-party>
<participant *ngIf="activeTab === 'Participant'"></participant >
```

that means there is always one tab active and will activate the correct component. Hope that will help. I always tried to make it as easy as possible with Angular, because this is what Angular stands for :)

about the problem on "NoProvidor". If you have the components in different ".model.ts" then you need to provide it in providers tab in the file, so other components can reach it. Explain the problem more and where you get it.